# How can get right to left android layout title

Tags: android-layout

I use the android:gravity="right" in my XML android 
but the title of app do not response 
How can I make the title from right to left?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:paddingLeft="0dp" 
     android:paddingRight="0dp" 
     android:paddingTop="0dp" 
     android:paddingBottom="0dp" 
     tools:context=".Main" 
     android:layout_gravity="right"  
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscr‌​een">  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".Main"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</RelativeLayout>